# How to find continuities with square root?

Tags: calculus

I don't understand how to find $$\frac{4-x^2}{3-\sqrt{x^2+5}}$$

The book says to multiply the equation by $\frac{3 + \sqrt {x^2+5}}{3 + \sqrt {x^2+5}}$. I don't understand where that comes from. It says the multiplication simplifies to "$3 + \sqrt {x^2+5}$" - I don't see how that's possible. Is the book wrong?

Comment: $(3-\sqrt{x^2+5})(3+\sqrt{x^2+5})=4-x^2$

Comment: This trick is commonly known as conjugate multiplication

Answer (score 2):

Just use the binomial identity

$$(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2,$$

which for $a=3$ and $b=\sqrt{x^2+5}$ yields

$$\frac{(4-x^2)(3+\sqrt{x^2+5})}{(3-\sqrt{x^2+5})(3+\sqrt{x^2+5})}=\frac{(4-x^2)(3+\sqrt{x^2+5})}{9-(x^2+5)}=\frac{(4-x^2)(3+\sqrt{x^2+5})}{(4-x^2)}$$

which is your desired result $(3+\sqrt{x^2+5}).$

Comment: I don't understand. What is represented by a? What is represented by b? What am I supposed to do with the result of 3+ $\sqrt{x^2+5}$?

Comment: @user6050977  $a = 3$ and $b = \sqrt{x^2 + 5}$.

Answer (score 2):

For this simplification, you need to know that $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$. It is important to recognize this, as this is something you need very often. You also need this when simplifying expressions with square roots in the denominator. In this case, this gives us the following simplification: $(3+\sqrt{x^2+5})(3-\sqrt{x^2+5})=3^2-\left(\sqrt{x^2+5}\right)^2=9-(x^2+5)=4-x^2$.

For this, we subsitute $a=3$ and $b=\sqrt{x^2+5}$ in the identity $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$.

This means that \begin{align*} \frac{4-x^2}{3-\sqrt{x^2+5}} &=\frac{4-x^2}{3-\sqrt{x^2+5}} \cdot \frac{3+\sqrt{x^2+5}}{3+\sqrt{x^2+5}} \\ &= \frac{(4-x^2)\left(3+\sqrt{x^2+5}\right)}{\left(3-\sqrt{x^2+5}\right)\left(3+\sqrt{x^2+5}\right)} \\ &= \frac{(4-x^2)\left(3+\sqrt{x^2+5}\right)}{4-x^2} \\ &= 3+\sqrt{x^2+5}\end{align*}

---

However, this is not valid for all $x$, since the former expression is not defined for all $x$, while the latter expression is. This is where the question is actually about: Finding the discontinuities of the function. For this, the following is useful:

> **Fact.** If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous, then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is continuous where $g(x) \neq 0$.

So we need to find where $3-\sqrt{x^2+5}=0$. So $\sqrt{x^2+5}=3$, so $x^2+5=9$ and $x^2=4$ which means that $x=2$ or $x=-2$. These both satisfy the given equation.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{4-x^2}{3-\sqrt{x^2+5}}=\frac{4-x^2}{3-\sqrt{x^2+5}}\cdot\frac{3+\sqrt{x^2+5}}{3+\sqrt{x^2+5}}=\frac{(4-x^2)(3+\sqrt{x^2+5})}{3^2-(x^2+5)}$$ $$=\frac{(4-x^2)(3+\sqrt{x^2+5})}{4-x^2}=3+\sqrt{x^2+5}$$

Comment: I don't understand. The book says the answer is "+- 2" How would I arrive at that from "3+ $\sqrt{x^2+5}$?"

Comment: @user6050977 The answer for _what_ is $\pm 2$? Is the question just to simplify this expression? A context would be needed.

Comment: It says, "Has a removable discontinuity at +-2."

Comment: @user6050977 When you substitute $x=\pm 2$ in the expression, you get the result as $\frac00$, which is indeterminate. So, now you simplify it this way and remove the term from the denominator and get $3+\sqrt{x^2+5}$, and the resulting function is defined at $x=\pm2$. Even though the original function is undefined at $x=\pm2$, just by separately defining the function at those two points will make the function continuous. So, you can remove the discontinuity.